# AttributeError: module 'caffe2.python._import_c_extension' has no attribute 'get_cudnn_version'

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe2

I'm struggling with this error for a few days now and I have no clue how to solve this. This is the error I get when I try to import the core module from the Caffe2 package.

```
from caffe2.python import core

AttributeError: module 'caffe2.python._import_c_extension' has no attribute 'get_cudnn_version'
```

I searched a lot on Google but couldn't find any answers that could solve this problem. Does someone know how to solve this?

Comment: I got the same error , I reinstalled cuda 9 and cudnn and it got resolved.